# Does kernel 4.4.6 come automatically with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS -> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS update?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

Today I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS and kernel 3.13.0-83 in my 64 bit laptop. With this kernel version I have still same problem of ''Kernel panic ...'' announcements and required reboot actions as with earlier kernel 3.13.xx versions.

I am waiting for online update to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to this same laptop.

Does this online update to Ubuntu 16.04 make AUTOMATICALLY also change of new kernel to 4.4.6 ? Or should I change kernel somehow separately ? How stable this kernel 4.4.6 is ? Brgds Kauko Peltonen

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 16.04 will be shipped with kernel 4.4.

If you upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, you will get kernel 4.4 installed.

Ubuntu kernel numbers do not match exactly the mainline versions. It will be 4.4.0-xx, that will be based on the latest 4.4.x mainline version.

You can install kernel 4.4 to Ubuntu 14.04 without upgrading to 16.04 by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Regarding "how stable is 4.4.6", it can't be answered as it will be based on opinions.

Comment: Pilot6 hello ! Today I tryed to upgrade my kernel to 4.4 with the sudo command you adviced, but - for some reason - the ugrade process doeas not start and sudo informs instead that ''E: Not correct function'' (sorry for my possible uncorrect translation into English) here the same in Finnish: ''E: Virheellinen toiminto linux-generic-lts-xenial''

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? To get output in English, run the command with prefix `LANG=C`, like `LANG=C sudo apt-get......`

Comment: Oops, I missed `install` in the command. I fixed it. @KaukoPeltonen

Comment: Pilot6 hi, Thanks for replies !! 1.) My kernel version today is 3.13.0-85. 2.) So, the corect sudo command is sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial. Thank you !! Kauko

Comment: Run the updated command, and you will get kernel 4.4. But that may cause some trouble with video drivers. But you still will be able to boot from 3.13 kernel using grub.

Comment: Hi, do you mean I can go back to kernel 3.13.0-85 using grub of kernel 4.4 or from grub of kernel 3.13.0-85 ?? I want to avoid risk or possibility to end into situation that, I fail in this process and - in the end - I have to re-install Ubuntu 14.04 from the disk, i.e. from the very beginning etc ... Brdgs Kauko

Comment: You can always boot with any of previously installed kernels. They are not removed automatically. So it is quite safe if you know how to get into grub menu.

Comment: OK, I shall try tomorrow and ... let's hope for the best.  I'll inform you the results. Brdgs, Kauko

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the distribution upgrade will also update the kernel. However, keep in mind that the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, will be offered automatically as soon as 16.04.01 is released and not from the first 16.04 release.